# Linux program - reverse highlighted text

Tags: linux, flash, ubuntu, driver, prezi

I want to develop a program that will run on the background of my Ubuntu 12.04 so when some text is selected in some textbox of any running program and some key-combination is pressed (like ctrl-F12), the text will be cut, reversed, and pasted in the same place.

I know some programs that do it on windows.

It is useful in some programs and web-pages that do not support right-to-left languages like arabic and hebrew - the letters are printed from left to right so the text becomes reversed.

More specifically I need it in [Prezi](http://www.prezi.com) that has this kind of bug in their embedded flash editor (I thought about writing a chrome-plugin, but I don't think such plugin can manipulate the selected text inside flash objects).

Do you know if such a program exist? Where should I start reading in order to develop a program with such capabilities (manipulate selected text in other programs)?

Thanks

Comment: So, um, what's your question? :)

Comment: @Miguel - I thought the questions are obvious, but I added them anyway.

Comment: haha, sorry. I just don't want anything to get closed, or down-voted. :)

Comment: Enjoy your quality time with the ICCCM...

Answer (score 0):

My partial solution - A python script that reverses the clipboard text:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk

clipboard = Gtk.Clipboard.get(Gdk.SELECTION_CLIPBOARD)
# if you want to take the selected text without copying, set primary to:
# Gtk.Clipboard.get(Gdk.SELECTION_PRIMARY)
# (doesn't always work)
primary = clipboard 

def run():
    text = primary.wait_for_text()
    if not isinstance(text, str):
        return
    reversed_text = u''.join(reversed(text.decode('utf-8')))
    clipboard.set_text(reversed_text, -1)
    clipboard.store()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Then define a keyboard shortcut to run the script (I used alt-Insert), and reverse selected the by copying it to the clipboard, call the script and paste it back (ctrl-Insert, alt-Insert, shift-Insert).

I'm still looking for a better solution, so I could use a single keyboard shortcut without overriding the clipboard.

Comment: PRIMARY is supposed to be the one to use that doesn't disturb the clipboard, but as you've seen not everyone plays nice.

Comment: Is PRIMARY suppose to let me override the selected text?

Comment: No, it can only tell you what the user has highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an input method for Emacs that will type text in reverse:

```lisp
(defun reverse-input-method (key)
  (if buffer-read-only
      (list key)
    (if (setq new key)
        (list new ?\2) ;; ?\2 == backwards char
      (list key ?\2))))

(defun reverse-input-activate (&optional arg)
  "Activate reverse-im input method.
With arg, activate reverse-im input method if and only if arg is
positive.

While this input method is active, the variable
`input-method-function' is bound to the function
`reverse-input-method'."
  (if (and arg
           (< (prefix-numeric-value arg) 0))
      (unwind-protect
          (progn
            (quail-hide-guidance)
            (quail-delete-overlays)
            (setq describe-current-input-method-function nil))
        (kill-local-variable 'input-method-function))
    (setq inactivate-current-input-method-function 'reverse-input-inactivate)
    (setq describe-current-input-method-function 'reversr-input-help)
    (quail-delete-overlays)
    (if (eq (selected-window) (minibuffer-window))
        (add-hook 'minibuffer-exit-hook 'quail-exit-from-minibuffer))
    (set (make-local-variable 'input-method-function)
         'reverse-input-method)))

(defun reverse-input-inactivate ()
  "Inactivate reverse-im input method."
  (interactive)
  (reverse-input-activate -1))

(defun reverse-input-help ()
  (interactive)
  (with-output-to-temp-buffer "*Help*"
    (princ "Inserts text in reverse order.")))

(provide 'reverse-im)

(register-input-method "reverse-im" "UTF-8" 'reverse-input-activate "<<"
                       "Input method for \"typing characters in reverse\".")
```

You could save it in, for example, ~/.emacs.d/reverse-im/reverse-im.el and then add these lines to .emacs

```lisp
(add-to-list 'load-path (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/reverse-im/"))
(require 'reverse-im)
```

Then use [KeySnail](https://github.com/mooz/keysnail/wiki) Firefox plugin to call emacs when you need to edit text (you'd need to set your text editor in .bashrc or whatever you use to store your shell variables to `emacsclient` and use [K2Emacs](https://raw.github.com/myuhe/KeySnail_Plugin/master/K2Emacs.ks.js) plugin of KeySnail, or modify your .keysnail.js to invoke Emacs when you need that.

There's similar plugin for Vim called Vimperator, but I didn't use it.

Comment: As I mentioned before, the textbox is inside a flash object - so I don't think you can manipulate it with javascript.